# Parameterised input values while using Terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We have been using Terraform EKS module and trying to parametrize 'eks_managed_node_groups' values based on the development and production environment. We have used file() and variable approaches but both resulted in the error.

varibales.tf

```
variable "eks_cluster_nodegroups" {
  description = "Nodegroups of the EKS cluster"
}
```

.tfvars

```
eks_cluster_nodegroups = <<EOF
{
    ng-1 = {
      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 2
      desired_size = 1

      instance_types = ['t3.small']
      capacity_type  = 'SPOT' //ON_DEMAND
    }
}
EOF
```

eks.tf

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 18.0"
.....
.....
eks_managed_node_groups = var.eks_cluster_nodegroups
.....
}
```

Thank you.

EKS module: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsondecode` to convert your string to TF object:

```
eks_managed_node_groups = jsondecode(var.eks_cluster_nodegroups)
```

Also it would be easier not to use JSON string in the first place for your `eks_cluster_nodegroups`.

Comment: Sorry. Same error. jsondecode does not help.

Comment: @BhaumikPatel Its not possible to get the same error with my code. This probably means means that your code in question is not the real code that you are using.

Comment: Error: Error in function call
│ Call to function "jsondecode" failed: invalid character 'n'.

Comment: @BhaumikPatel Its different error, and the issue is that your string is not even a valid JSON. What do you want to do exactly? Why do you use strings in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, the attachment is not allowed in comment. You are right last line of error message is different. I doubt if .tfvars is JSON.

Comment: We use the same code base i.e eks.tf file for both dev and prod, but compute capacity for dev/prod is different so we are trying to parameterized 'eks_managed_node_groups 
' block.

Comment: @BhaumikPatel If you want to use is as string, make sure this is **valid** json in the first place. Your code will not work in any programming language, as its not json.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to syntax.

More info:
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/multi-line-string-variable/44172